# After matching a pattern ignore remaing blocks of string (URLs) using REGEX

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am having few URLs as below and I want to check whether they match a regex or not.

URLs

```
https://www.amazon.in/Fire-Boltt-Display-Sports-Smartwatch-Tracking/dp/B09YV4RG4D
https://www.amazon.in/Fire-Boltt-Display-Sports-Smartwatch-Tracking/dp/B09YV4RG4D/
https://www.amazon.in/Fire-Boltt-Display-Sports-Smartwatch-Tracking/dp/B09YV4RG4D?tag=goog-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1
https://www.amazon.in/dp/B087FXHB6J?tag=goog-21&linkCode=ogi&th=1&psc=1
https://www.amazon.in/dp/B087FXHB6J
```

Regex

```
/(https:\/\/www.amazon.in\/)([A-Za-z0-9-_]{0,}\/?)(dp\/[a-zA-z0-9]{0,})(\/?)(\??)/gm
```

Here is the test results from browser console
[image]

and from `https://regex101.com/`
[image]

My question is, What I am doing wrong as 2nd and 4th scenarios are failing?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for a match only, you can match `/dp/` as it is present in all the examples, and optionally match `/` or `?` at the end of the pattern followed by optional non whitespace characters.

```
^https:\/\/www\.amazon\.in(?:\/[\w-]*)*\/dp\/[a-zA-z0-9]+(?:[\/?]\S*)?$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJnkXM/1)